# Correct way to GET a Rails resource from their id or other unique field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

We have an API where we can GET a user in two ways:

1. Through his default Rails-generated `id` (unique, autoincrement)
2. Through a unique field `employee_id` (the ID of the employee in an external system, we don't have related employee controller/model/table)

Here's how it's exposed as URIs:

```
/users/:id
/users/employee_id/:employee_id
```

Both sends the call to the `users#show` method that will look for either `params[:id]` or `params[:employee_id]` and then return the user if it exists.

I can't really tell why, but the second URI feels wrong.

What is a standard or better way to access a ressource from different unique IDs?

We're thinking of doing this using two calls (first to `index` to get users matching the `employee_id`, then to `show` to retrieve the user info from the `id` we got), but I'm curious about alternatives.

Comment: Are the employee ids also numerical? Can you query `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :x OR employee_id = x` and be sure to get the correct result?

Comment: In our case, the `employee_id` is a number stored as a string (we can't be sure it won't ever contain something else than digits). It would be possible to query by both, but it doesn't seem super clean. In this case, having a user with and `employee_id` that is also a valid `id` would return two results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very restful looking.

Could try something like this...

Add a non-resource route...

```
get 'employees(/:employee_id)', to: 'users#employee'
```

add an `employee` action to your users controller, which will look up the user by the supplied id

```
  def employee
    @user = User.find_by(employee_id: params[:employee_id])
    render json: @user
  end
```

and now you have a restful looking API

```
/users/:id
/employees/:employee_id
```

Comment: I like the idea of making it more restful looking this way. Does having an employee route returning a user resource makes sense? How about someone wanting to update a user from their employee_id? This shouldn't happen, but I'm curious about what you think.

Comment: seems that is what you wanted. If you want them to update as well, you could.  If that is the piece of info your users are most familiar with -- it's not a horrid idea.  Of course at that point, maybe you flip it and make an employee controller you can access via a user_id. This is all really about what makes the most sense for your situation.